# setting the first line read from a file if it is an int, as the end limit of a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Currently learning python, what I need to do is set the limit of a for loop equal to the int version of the first item read in a file

for example:
if a file contains the list:
10
1
2
3
4
...

I want the first line which contains 10, as the end limit for a for loop.
or maybe there is another way to accomplish this, that would also be appreciated.

here is what i have code:

```
otherFile = input("Do you have a file to open? (Y/N): ")

while(otherFile == 'Y' or otherFile == 'y'):

    totalSum = 0

    try:
        with open(input("which file would you like to open? "), "r") as file:
            for line in file:
                totalSum += int(line)
                print(line, end="")
            print()
            print("Total Sum is: ", totalSum)

    except FileNotFoundError:
       print("File name invalid, Please enter valid name.")
       print()

    except ValueError:
       print("Invalid data type within file.")

    otherFile = input("Do you have another file to open? (Y/N): ")

print("Goodbye")
```

I tried to read only the first line and turning that into an int, then setting it to limit but it did not work, i show that below:

```
        with open(input("which file would you like to open? "), "r") as file:
            numLines = int(file.readline())
            for line in numLines: <---------- #what I tried
                totalSum += int(line)
                print(line, end="")
            print()
            print("Total Sum is: ", totalSum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# just showing what is in this file
>>> with open('file_1', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print(line.rstrip())
... 
2
abc
def
ghi
jkl

# print only 2 lines
>>> with open('file_1', 'r') as f:
...     for _ in range(int(next(f))):
...         print(next(f).rstrip())
... 
abc
def
```

If you do it this way and there is a file where the number in the first line is greater than the total number of lines, you will have to handle the `StopIteration` on your own.

Comment: thanks, i tried your suggestion and it seems to work, although the output I am getting is somethine like this: <built-in method rstrip of str object at 0x111da5880>   as opposed to the list of integers I was getting before, is there a way to display the integers?

Comment: @streamybroom Did you forget the `()` after `.rstrip`? `next(f).rstrip()`?

Answer (score 1):

Do not cast string into int if you need a list you may create an integer list like this

```
integers="10 20 30 40"
integers = list(map(int,integers.split(" ")))
```

Following code can be useful for setting the limit for range

```
x=fh.readline()
limit_to_set=int(x.split(" ")[0])
for i in range(0,limit_to_set):
    # perform your operation
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a code like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', delimiter = ' ')
num = df.columns[0]
```

num here is the integer you are seeking, than you can run your loop like this:

```
for i in range(num):
```

when dealing with integers you should use `range()`